# Remove "You are using Wordpress 3.2.1" from Right Now Dashboard Widget

Tags: theme-development, functions, dashboard

I'm looking for a to hide the text on the dashboard that says "You are using WordPress 3.2.1" in the Right Now widget. Not that we don't love WordPress, but for our use-case (where we'll be providing this WP install to dozens, if not hundreds of people), I'd like to get as much stuff out of there that's not needed (and that could eventually confuse them). I saw that the Right Now Dashboard is in /wp-admin/includes/dashboard.php -- but can't figure out how to change/remove that text. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a trick to get rid of this using the `gettext` filter for translations.

This basically replaces it with nothing.

```
add_filter('gettext', 'remove_admin_stuff', 20, 3);

function remove_admin_stuff( $translated_text, $untranslated_text, $domain ) {

    $custom_field_text = 'You are using <span class="b">WordPress %s</span>.';

    if ( is_admin() && $untranslated_text === $custom_field_text ) {
        return '';
    }

    return $translated_text;
}
```

Be aware that the version also shows in the footer and several other places, if you want a good breakdown check out the source of this plugin, it seems to have covered more or less all of it, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hide-wordpress-version/

Answer (score 0):

It is located within the update_right_now_message() function in wp-admin/includes/update.php but there is no hook for this and it is frowned upon to change WordPress core, especially since every time you upgrade core after this change, you will have to re-do it.

One thing you can do to not hack core and still achieve what you want is to enqueue a stylesheet for just the admin area and then just set the css for #wp-version-message { display:none; }  and problem solved.  It is still there, but nobody can see it.

Answer (score -3):

```
add_action('admin_footer', function(){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo ';(function($){ $("#wp-version-message").hide(); })(jQuery);';
    echo '</script>';
});
```

You can only hide it. To have it removed, hack the core and add a new conditional filter where it's output!